# F# convert Vector array to Media.Polygon PointCollection

Tags: wpf, vector, f#, polygons

Different data strucs are good/better for some things not so much for others.

Is there a way to convert a Vector array to be used by WPF Polygon?

```
let mutable nodes = [| Vector (100.0, 100.0); Vector (60.0, 20.0); Vector (80.0, 60.0); Vector(50.0, 100.0); Vector (100.0, 80.0); Vector (30.0, 140.0); Vector (20.0, 80.0); Vector (30.0, 30.0); |]

let spolyS : Point seq = Seq.ofArray [| Vector (0.0, 0.0); Vector (6.0, 2.0); Vector (8.0, 6.0); Vector(5.0, 10.0); Vector (10.0, 8.0); Vector (3.0, 14.0); Vector (-2.0, 8.0); Vector (-3.0, 3.0); |]
let seqFromArray1 = [| 1..10 |] :> seq<int>
let seqFromArray2 = [| 1 .. 10 |] |> Seq.ofArray
let seqFromArray3 = polyS :> seq<Point>

let mutable arrayList1 = new System.Collections.ArrayList(10)
for i in 1 .. 10 do arrayList1.Add(10) |> ignore
let seqCast : seq<int> = Seq.cast arrayList1

let mutable arrayList2 = new Media.PointCollection(10)
for i in 1 .. 10 do arrayList1.Add(10) |> ignore
let seqCast : seq<Point> = Seq.cast arrayList2
let spts : Point seq = Seq.ofArray polyS |> new Media.PointCollection
let spts : Point seq = Seq.ofArray polyS |> new Media.PointCollection
let spts : Point seq = Seq.ofArray polyS |> new Media.PointCollection(spts IEnumerable<Point>):unit
```

Comment: Well for one, don't use `ArrayList`. :-[

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
let vectors = [| Vector(100.0, 100.0); Vector(60.0, 20.0); ... |]
let points = vectors |> Array.map (fun v -> Point(v.X, v.Y))
let mediaPoints = Media.PointCollection(points)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Now I have a Polygon! and I'd like to fill it with an image .jpg ... I've tried several approaches and failed. Stackoverflow protocol may require me to ask another question(?) Here's a bit of what I've tried.       //let testPoly = new Shapes.Polygon()
//testPoly.Fill <- image
let quiltImageBrush = System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush() //quiltImageSource) //:@"C:\Users\Honu\Pictures\Two Rockets.jpg")
let quiltBitmapImage = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(System.Uri ( "C:\Users\Honu\Pictures\Two Rockets.jpg" ))
l Thanks for your help. Art